# Difference between MXBean, JMX and OSBean

Tags: java, jmx

I am new to this field of calculating CPU and memory usage using JMX and `MXBeans`. I just wanted to know what exactly JMX is and what is the difference between `MXBeans` and JMX? Is there anything called OSBeans also?

Comment: You might wanna take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9232132/use-of-jmx-and-how-to-use-for-existing-applications

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JMX is the acronym for Java Management Extensions. It's the technology provided by Java that supplies tools for managing and monitoring applications, system objects and others like devices, etc...

Before asking for a MXBean, you should know about MBeans. An `MBean` is basically a managed Java object, accessible through JMX.

An `MXBean` is a type of MBean that references only a predefined set of data types.

You can find more information in the [Java MBean Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jmx/mbeans/index.html).

According to OSBeans, as far as I know there's nothing about it in java. Maybe you mean `OperatingSystemMXBean` ([OperatingSystemMXBean](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/management/extension/com/sun/management/OperatingSystemMXBean.html)) which is a platform-specific management interface for the operating system on which the Java virtual machine is running.

Comment: yeah i mean OperatingSystemMXBean. how to calculate cpu and memory usage parameters using OperatingSystemMXBean and MXBean

Comment: @FAZ That's another question. Maybe this helps you to access those beans. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36155751/how-to-figure-out-the-cpu-usage-of-a-java-process-in-java/36156470#36156470

Comment: Check this as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18489273/how-to-get-percentage-of-cpu-usage-of-os-from-java